# Bookmarks in Power BI Desktop

Tags: button, powerbi, bookmarks

I am failing to make bookmarks work in my Power BI model.  Basically I have three charts namely Fixed Format, Measure Comparison and Actuals by Business Unit which I need to visualize on the first report page through the use of bookmarks.

I have attached the PBIX file through a link.

[Power BI Desktop File](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1uNoUpriq1AgKme_UqntiEUtV945MXT2t/view?usp=sharing)

Kindly assist with troubleshooting the problem and advise accordingly.

Best regards

Comment: Can you outline what you have tried to do, what is not working

Answer (score 0):

**Note: Never share your original data. You may affected by GDPR.**

Please check the attached report file from the link. I have implemented the Bookmarks for you as per my understanding.

[Report File Here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1-mszwxTwOKiGpc3h6gZ0Mj-op2KRwh_Z/view?usp=sharing)